# Proposal upvotes list

Tags: voting

I'm looking for a way to know if a delegate has upvoted for proposals, in proposal period.

In short, I want to know if a delegate is in this list: https://tzkt.io/governance/41/proposal

For ballot vote, we have GET ../<block_id>/votes/ballot_list on tezos-client. Anything similar for proposals upvoting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following RPC request will give you the current state of proposals:

```
nochem@peck ~/workspace/tezos () $ curl -s https://mainnet.api.tez.ie/chains/main/blocks/head/context/raw/json/votes/proposals?depth=1 | jq
[
  [
    "PtLimaPtLMwfNinJi9rCfDPWea8dFgTZ1MeJ9f1m2SRic6ayiwW",
    [
      "tz3e7LbZvUtoXhpUD1yb6wuFodZpfYRb9nWJ",
      "tz1ibcPVGK4Y8pcW4BYUsojiHoBKnZbyDGrX",
      "tz1i5PPsXa711EuZzped9jqPS8hGKsrCMB9f",
      "tz1gg5bjopPcr9agjamyu9BbXKLibNc2rbAq",
      "tz1gcna2xxZj2eNp1LaMyAhVJ49mEFj4FH26",
      "tz1ffYUjwjduZkoquw8ryKRQaUjoWJviFVK6",
      "tz1fJHFn6sWEd3NnBPngACuw2dggTv6nQZ7g",
      "tz1eDKeD934e22muFRzVHxZYvFFx39QKHyj3",
      "tz1eCs8nFQiKTqwcqQjKyz8QGMCQ4JAXbPS8",
      "tz1dNVDWPf3Q59SdJqnjdnu277iyvReiRS9M",
      "tz1cSoWttzYi9taqyHfcKS86b5M31SoaTQdg",
      "tz1bZ8vsMAXmaWEV7FRnyhcuUs2fYMaQ6Hkk",
      "tz1awotVZv3VdZL613qFuD4MP7hfeLZoEwWn",
      "tz1aqcYgG6NuViML5vdWhohHJBYxcDVLNUsE",
      "tz1aLrL64dyofDJQSP8rBip9GykihykWX548",
      "tz1ZgkTFmiwddPXGbs4yc6NWdH4gELW7wsnv",
      "tz1Y7939nK18ogD32jAkun8sCCH8Ab2tQfvv",
      "tz1R4PuhxUxBBZhfLJDx2nNjbr7WorAPX1oC",
      "tz1P6WKJu2rcbxKiKRZHKQKmKrpC9TfW1AwM",
      "tz1NoYvKjXTzTk54VpLxBfouJ33J8jwKPPvw",
      "tz1MivraUX9U6nmGAQkm7XkrNVmsPExEUT1W",
      "tz1LVqmufjrmV67vNmZWXRDPMwSCh7mLBnS3"
    ]
  ]
]
```

But, you have to filter by delegate yourself. There is no "per delegate" query.